# How do I correctly use derived classes as fields of a Microsoft Bond object

Tags: c#, events, bond

So there's no confusion, when I talk through my issue I am doing so as someone who is using the compiled classes that result from Bond schemas (that is to say I use "class" instead of "struct", etc.). I feel like it makes more cognitive sense to think of it this way.

I am using Microsoft Bond and I have a main class that has several properties, one of which is an instance of a derived class.

When creating an instance of the main class I have no problem setting the property to an instance of the derived class; however when I deserialize from binary back into the main class the property is now seen as its base class.

I have tried to cast it as the derived class but that throws a runtime exception.

The examples for using derived classes in the Bond documentation/manual have you specifying the derived class at the time of deserialization, but I am not deserializing just the derived class but the main class.

Here's an example of how I have the bond schema set up

```
struct BaseExample
{
   0: int property1;
}

struct DerivedExample : BaseExample
{
   0: int property2;
}

struct MainExample
{
   0: BaseExample mainProperty;
}
```

In usage I am setting mainProperty to an instance of the DerivedExample class. 
What I'd expect is that after deserialization, mainProperty is still of type DerivedExample (containing property2) but what I am seeing instead is mainProperty is of type BaseExample (and doesn't contain property2)

Am I forced to use generics to do this or is there something I am missing?

**EDIT: Adding examples**

My code that uses the classes generated from the Bond schemas is like this.

We have a calling service that creates a message of this type and uses Bond to serialize it into a byte array before sending it on a stream.

```
var message = new MainExample();

var derivedExample = new DerivedExample()
{
    property1 = 1,
    property2 = 2,        
};
message.mainProperty = derivedExample;

// This block is all from the Bond examples
var output = new OutputBuffer();
var writer = new CompactBinaryWriter<OutputBuffer>(output);
Serialize.To(writer, message);

SendMessage(output.Data.Array);
```

Now we have a receiving service that is going to take this message off the stream and use Bond to deserialize it back into an object.

```
void HandleMessage(byte[] messageBA)
{
    // This block is all from the Bond examples
    var input = new InputBuffer(messageBA);
    var reader = new CompactBinaryReader<InputBuffer>(input);
    MainExample message = Deserialize<BondEvent>.From(reader);

    // mainProperty is now of type BaseExample and not DerivedExample
    message.mainProperty.property1; // is accessable
    message.mainProperty.property2; // will not compile

    DerivedExample castedProperty = message.mainProperty as DerivedExample; // fails at runtime
}
```

Full disclosure: I am actually using F# but I figured it would be better to do these in C#

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're setting to what and what you're seeing that is wrong. Can you edit the question to show how you're creating, setting, serializaing, deserializing, and inspecting the structs?

Comment: I reworded some things and added examples, I am sorry I don't know how to make this simpler to explain. The devil is definitely in the details with regards to my question. But if there's something specific I can clarify please let me know and I will try.

My belief is that if I am serializing a concrete implementation of a derived type, the deserializer should be able to instantiate the same type that was serialized. I am not seeing that, so either I'm doing it wrong or it's not possible, which is fine I just need to know for sure before I switch to using generics (which does work).

Comment: Got what I needed (the edit to the `MainExample` struct that changed the type of `mainProperty`) to answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slicing behavior that you are observing when deserializing is expected with the schemas as written. The `MainExample.mainProperty` field is of type `BaseExample`, so when it is serialized, only the `BaseExample` fields are written. It doesn't matter which runtime type is used. Additionally, when it is deserialized, only `BaseExample` fields will be realized.

When dealing with inheritance and polymorphism, Bond does not include any type information in serialized payloads: it leaves the decision about how to model this up to the schema designer. This stems from Bond's philosophy of only paying for what you use.

Depending on the data you are modeling, I see two ways to design your schema:

1. generics
2. `bonded`

## Generics

As mentioned in the question, the `MainExample` struct could be made generic:

```
struct MainExample<T>
{
    0: T mainProperty;
}
```

This essentially allows you to easily create a bunch of different structs with similar shapes. But these structs will not have an "is a" relationship. Methods like `HandleMessage` likely will also have to be generic, causing a generic cascade.

## Bonded

To include a field in another struct that is polymorphic in type, make the field a [`bonded` field](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_cs.html#understanding-bondedt). Bonded fields do not slice when serialized. Also, they are not immediately deserialized, so the receiving side has a chance to pick the appropriate type to deserialize into.

In the .bond file, we'd have this:

```
struct MainExample
{
   0: bonded<BaseExample> mainProperty;
}
```

To serialize, the following:

```
var message = new MainExample();

var derivedExample = new DerivedExample()
{
    property1 = 1,
    property2 = 2,        
};
message.mainProperty = new Bonded<DerivedExample>(derivedExample);
// NB: new Bonded<BaseExample>(derivedExample) WILL slice
```

And to deserialize:

```
void HandleMessage(byte[] messageBA)
{
    // This block is all from the Bond examples
    var input = new InputBuffer(messageBA);
    var reader = new CompactBinaryReader<InputBuffer>(input);
    MainExample message = Deserialize<BondEvent>.From(reader);

    DerivedExample de = message.mainProperty.Deserialize<DerivedExample>();
}
```

When using `bonded` fields for polymorphism, we will need to have some way of knowing which most-derived type to deserialize into. Sometimes this is known from context external to the payload (e.g., perhaps each of the messages handled only has one type). Other times, we need to embed this information in the common part of the payload. A common way to do this is with an enum:

```
enum PropertyKind
{
    Base;
    Derived;
}

struct MainExample
{
    0: bonded<BaseExample> mainProperty;
    1: PropertyKind mainPropertyKind = Base;
}
```

There's a fully worked example of doing this kind of dispatch in the C# [polymorphic_container](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/tree/master/examples/cs/core/polymorphic_container) example in the Bond repository.

## `OutputBuffer.Data.Array`

I notice that in the code to send a message, there's the following line, which contains a bug:

```
SendMessage(output.Data.Array);
```

The `OutputBuffer.Data` property is an `ArraySegment<byte>`, which is used to represent a slice of some other array. This slice may be shorter than the entire array (the `Count` property), and it may start at an offset other than 0 (the `Offset` property). Most I/O libraries have an overload like `SendMessage(byte[] buf, int offset, int count)` that can be used in cases like this.

The default array backing an `OutputBuffer` is 65K, so there's almost certainly a bunch of extra data being sent.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, we really appreciate it!